# Vue.js - Export an axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, interceptor, es6-modules

Good evening everyone, here I have a problem with my interceptor in VueJS. I don't understand where my problem comes from, and I'm pulling my hair out...

I've watched several tutorials, I've watched several topics on stackoverflow, but I don't understand what's going on at all.

When I put a debugger on, it's triggered, but when I switch to "axios.interceptors" it tells me that axios is undefined, it's incomprehensible...

```
import axios from 'axios';

debugger;
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL_API,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})
```

The code above is called in my VueX Store.

```
import Http from "../../api/http";

export default {
    state: {
        customers: {},
        customer: {},
    },
    getters: {
        customers: state => state.customers,
    },
    mutations: {
        SET_CUSTOMERS(state, customers) {
            state.customers = customers;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadCustomers({commit}) {
            Http.get('/customers').then(result => {
                commit('SET_CUSTOMERS', result.data.data );
            }).catch(error => {
                throw new Error(`API ${error}`);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

I want to trigger http code 401 to logout my user and destroy the token in the browser.

If anyone could help me, I would be delighted, thank you very much.

Regards,
Christophe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people which are wondering how the issue has been solved, there is my code :)

success.js

```
export default function (response) {
    return response
}
```

failure.js
import router from 'vue-router'

```
export default function (error) {
    switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
            localStorage.removeItem('jwt.token')

            router.push({
                name: 'Login'
            })
            break
    }

    return Promise.reject(error)
}
```

adding this to main.js

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt.token')
if (token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token
}
```

create api.js which is my client for all the request, so my request are always passing by this.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import success from '@/interceptors/response/success'
import failure from '@/interceptors/response/failure'

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL_API
})

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt.token')

    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`

    return config
})

api.interceptors.response.use(success, failure)

export default api
```

I hope it will be usefull :)

Comment: Exactly, I used the same approach and it did work.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in the interceptor [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors), just below the example interceptors, if you use an instance, you have to add the interceptor to it:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL_API,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // Any status code within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    // Any status codes outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: Wow amazing ! Thank you Dan ! But I have a new problem that has just come up. As a result, I arrive on my page, for example "dashboard" and the first time the token is not read, so I have a 401 request. I have to refresh my page so that it is read and I am not disconnected. It seems that the "instance" method is not the best, am I wrong?

Comment: You're welcome.  No, that sounds unrelated to the instance.  You're already using the instance, this answer only modifies it to add the interceptor before exporting it.

Comment: @Christophe I'm experiencing the same issue as you did sometime back where on the first time the token is not read from the localStorage. I wonder, how did you fix this issue?

Comment: @CoderAbsolute i've added my code in the following answer, i hope it will help